# Parse multi-level xml to .plist Object-c

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, nsdictionary, multi-level

can you help me parse multi-level xml to .plist, xml file:

```
  <item type="text">
    <id>
      783026
    </id>
    <rating>
     45
    </rating>
    <title>
      <![CDATA[Российские реалии)]]>
    </title>
 </item>
  <item type="image">
    <id>
      783034
    </id>
    <rating>
      47
    </rating>
    <title>
      <![CDATA[скраб...]]>
    </title>
  </item>
```

How I can parse this xml to .plist, and fill UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

iOS provides the [`NSXMLParser class`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for parsing XML.  You can use the XML parser to create an array of items, and set up your table view data source to use that array.